# ParameterExpression of type 'Data' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'System.Object'

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, delegates, expression

i'm trying to write a function that checks the methods with a specific attribute and collects info about them. Then, i need to compile them into expression so it's overhead will be minimal. But when i try to run my function, i get error that i put into the header.

My code is:

```
MethodInfo? method_info = handler_class.GetType().GetMethod("Handler");
if (method_info == null) continue;
ParameterInfo[] prms = method_info.GetParameters();
Type param_type = prms[0].ParameterType;

ParameterExpression[] prm_exprs = new ParameterExpression[] { 
    Expression.Parameter(param_type, "data")
};
MethodCallExpression method_expression = Expression.Call(
    Expression.Constant(handler_class),
    method_info,
    prm_exprs
);

Debug.WriteLine(method_expression.ToString());

Expression<Action<object>> le = Expression.Lambda<Action<object>>(
    method_expression,
    "HandlerCaller",
    true,
    prm_exprs
);
Action<object> handler = le.Compile();
```

Comment: You haven't shown the class definition of the called class.

Comment: I just have a method named Handler. @DavidL

Comment: If you are building an expression, remember that there are no implicit conversion operators. You have to build them all yourself. tip; let C# compile an example expression, then either debug the expression tree or disassemble the expression code.